# How to create a dynamic copy of an array inside a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

For implementing a specific function dealing with arrays I need to create a copy of the array the function gets as an argument. However, I get an error when I run the code. Is there anything wrong with these two lines inside the function?

```
void shift(int array[], int length, int offset)
{
    int* array2=new int[length];
    array2[]=array[];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well it would be much simpler if you used [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, but now you can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy the memory.

Comment: I am not allowed to use vectors yet as it is for an assignment, is there something else I can do?

Comment: And don't forget `delete [] array2;` when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot copy an array like that.

array2 and array are starting addresses in memory so assigning them to one another makes no sense.

instead you need to copy the contents

this can be done e.g. by the c runtime function memcpy or by using std::copy

```
memcpy(array2, array, length);
```

or

```
std::copy(array, array + length, array2);
```

Comment: thank you, this now makes sense. Also, do I need to delete array2 after I used it? or is it deleted automatically as it is a dynamic array?

Comment: you allocated `array2` on the heap (new) and as such need to be deleted when it is no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator. Moreover even if such an operator would exist this syntax in any case is invalid

```
array2[]=array[];
```

If you need to get a copy of an array you have to copy element by element. For example you could use standard algorithm `std::copy` declared in header `<algorithm>` or standard C function `memcpy` declared in header `<cstring>`

For example your function could look like

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int * shift( int array[], int length, int offset )
{
    int *array2 = new int[length];
    std::copy_n( array + offset, length, array2 );

    return array2;
}
```

With using memcpy the copy operation would look

```
#include <cstring>

//...

std::memcpy( array2, array + offset, length * sizeof( int ) );
```